# Does Javascript features change by browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I wonder something about Javascript. Does Javascript features or behaviors change by browsers?

While I was working Javascript `XMLHttpRequest` `upload` method, I noticed that Internet Explorer sending small bytes but Firefox and Google chrome sending big bytes. So while I was sending big data with Firefox or Chrome, server is giving `OutOfMemory` exception.

**I am editing post with image details.**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes they do. Actually most browsers support a close set of features but it is always IE which falls behinds and does not comply to standards.

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'small bytes' and 'big bytes'. Never realized they came in sizes... Do you have some sample code that demostrate the behavior you describe?

Comment: Are you asking for [javascript features](http://pointedears.de/scripts/test/es-matrix/) or [DOM features](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dom+incompatibilities) (of which `XMLHttpRequest` is part of)? Yes, both have very different browser support.

Comment: I edited the post with images. Same XHR upload process event results are here

Answer (score -1):

No Javascript features doesn't change from browser to browser, it depends upon their [**Javascript rendering machine**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine) (interpreter is the difference).

For example:

- Google - v8 engine
- Safari - JavaScriptCore

Comment: i guess thats what he does mean by feature changes .

Comment: JavaScript is being rendered? Never heard of that.

Answer (score -1):

yes there is some differences (a hanful actually)

here are some examples

### 1- accessing the float proparity

because float is a reserved keyword you can access it in ie with:

```
document.getElementById("id").style.styleFloat = "left";
```

while in fire fox it will be :

```
document.getElementById("id").style.cssFloat = "left";
```

### 2-to access a class attribute you can do the following in ie :

```
document.getElementById("id").getAttribute("className");
```

while in fire fox :

```
document.getElementById("id").getAttribute("class");
```

these are the things that i had an experience with . but mostly every one is using jquery now so no need to worry about those . but here are some articles about them

http://www.impressivewebs.com/7-javascript-differences-between-firefox-ie/

http://www.willowdesign.info/blog/tag/javascript-browser-differences/

[JS cross browser inconsistencies/differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422287/js-cross-browser-inconsistencies-differences)

http://technologypost.blogspot.com/2008/07/ie-vs-firefox-javascript-differences_05.html